# WebStorm: Angular Material HTML tags shown as 'not a known element' but compiles and works fine

Tags: angular, angular-material, webstorm

I am currently using Angular 2 Material Design for a very small project. To include the modules I need, I created a `MaterialModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

I imported this module in my `AppModule` class. Now, when I try to use the HTML tags provided by the Material Design modules, WebStorm gives me this error:

> Angular: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element: 1. If 'mat-toolbar' is
>   an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. 2.
>   If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'
>   to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

[image: image showing where the error occurs]

Also, autocomplete isn't working for these tags which makes the whole thing rather annoying.

Funny enough, the project compiles successfully and the resulting page works fine with the full material design features.

Did I do something wrong / in an unusual way in my `MaterialModule`, so that only Angular works with it but WebStorm sees it as an error?

Comment: The error comes not from WebStorm, but from Angular language service...

Comment: observed the similar issue, too, but restarting seems to fix it - can't see the error anymore, despite still having Angular service enabled

Comment: may be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14961; see if updating typescript to 2.5.2+ helps